# LDAP authentication only for users in a specific group (CN)

Tags: php, active-directory

I have been trying to figure out how to allow users who are a member of a specific group in my AD only to be able to login and I am kind of lost. Can you please help me by giving the right code for this. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20496143/5930557 Read here

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I found this code and it works for me.
https://samjlevy.com/php-login-script-using-ldap-verify-group-membership/

Hope this wil be helpful to anyone with the same problem as mine! :)

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of these examples around when you look for them.

One of them (that also works with LDAP and not only AD) is https://gist.github.com/heiglandreas/5689592